# How to remove canonical and title from AMP posts

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, canonical-link

Due to my SEO Plugin, canonical link and and title tag appears twice.

I tried to remove it in the AMP via Hook:

```
add_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'r23_amp_post_template_add', 11 );

function r23_amp_post_template_add( $amp_template ) { 
remove_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_title' ); 
remove_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_canonical' ); 
}
```

But, unfortnuatly, it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As I can guess, you're using [Amp for Wordpress by Automattic plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/).

You're on the right way. Just change the priority:

```
add_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'r23_amp_post_template_add', 9 );

function r23_amp_post_template_add($amp_template) {
    remove_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_title' );
    remove_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_canonical' );
}
```

*Tested and works*